# Solving integral with residues

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I have to solve the integral $\int_{-∞}^\infty \frac{cos(x)dx}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}$ using residues.

Here's my attempt to the point where I am stuck:

Noting that $\cos(x)=\text{Re}(e^{ix})$.  We can write

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}\,dx=\operatorname{Re}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}\,dx\right)$$
By the residue theorem, the integral around the semi-circular contour is just $2\pi i$ times the sum of f's residues at its poles in the upper half plane. So, if we show that as R goes to infinity, the integral on the big semicircle goes to 0, then we'll just have the integral on the real axis of $f(z)$.

However, I am stuck at calculating the residues specifically, since we are dealing with upper half plane I assume we need to calculate residues when $z=ia$ and $z=ib$, however when I take the limit and plug directly I get $0$ in the denominator. I don't know what's wrong here. I'd highly appreciate if someone could help me arrive at the full solution.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. You might find it easier if you use$$\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}=\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+b^2}\right).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you forgot that we should consider $\lim_{z\to\zeta}(z-\zeta)f(z)$ where $\zeta$ is the **simple** pole. You seem to have only calculated $\lim_{z\to\zeta}f(z)$, which does not exist (precisely because $\zeta$ is a pole). N.B. this method doesn't work for poles of order higher than one. So, if $a=b$ then this approach will *not* work and you'll have to much more carefully compute the residue, since the pole will be of second order.

Tip: $$\frac{z-ia}{z^2+a^2}\to\frac{1}{2ai}$$By L'Hopital's rule. Alternatively consider $z^2+a^2=(z-ia)(z+ia)$ so if you remove the $z-ia$ factor you obtain $z+ia\to2ai$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can I ask why there's no $(z^2+b^2)$ in the denominator and $e^{iz}$ in the numerator? When I take the limit you provided for $ia$ by factoring and removing the $z-ia$ factor, it results in $\frac{e^{-a}}{2ia+b^2-a}$.

Comment: @Arbatus Almost, it should be: $$\frac{e^{-a}}{2a(b^2-a^2)\cdot i}$$In my post I didn’t include the $z^2+b^2$ terms etc. because the main point is correctly calculating what happens to $(z-ia)/(z^2+a^2)$. There is a general principle here: if $g$ is holomorphic at $\zeta$ and $h$ has a **simple** pole there, then $\mathrm{Res}(g\cdot h;\zeta)=g(\zeta)\cdot\mathrm{Res}(h;\zeta)$. So, you can focus on the $h$ term when thinking about the residue. Here I take $h=(z^2+a^2)^{-1}$ and calculate its residue separately, and $g(z)=e^{iz}/(z^2+b^2)$ can just be evaluated at $ia$ easily.

Comment: Could you please explain how to proceed further, after finding residue for $ia$: $\frac{e^{-a}}{2a(b^2-a^2)\cdot i}$ and similarly, for $ib$? There are still many variables left, how do I get closer to the final answer?

Comment: Well you just add them up! Multiply by $2\pi i$, and we find we need to sum: $$\frac{\pi e^{-a}}{a(b^2-a^2)}-\frac{\pi e^{-b}}{b(b^2-a^2)}=\frac{\pi}{ab}\cdot\frac{be^{-a}-ae^{-b}}{b^2-a^2}$$

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this and I now get the answer. Am I correct to interpret $\pi\frac{be^{-a}+ae^{-b}}{b^2-a^2}$ as the final solution of the integral, though?

Comment: @Arbatus I messed up the algebra, see my edited comment. That's now the correct value of the integral (you need to do work to show the large arc integral vanishes though)

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply this formula to your two points: $Res(f,c)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{{x \to c}}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}((z-c)^nf(z)),\ where\ n=1,\ and\ f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+a^2)(z^2+b^2)}$. The limits should be easy. Then take the real part of the solution.

Comment: Yes, I have edited right now. The formula is general for poles.